# Abandoned named semaphore not released

Tags: c#, .net, semaphore

when a C# program holds a named semaphore, it does not seem to be released when the application is terminated early (for example by pressing Ctrl+C or closing the console window). At least not until all instances of the process have terminated.

With a named mutex an AbandonedMutexException is raised in this case but not with a semaphore. How do you prevent one program instance from stalling when another program instance has been terminated early?

```
class Program
{
    // Same with count > 1
    private static Semaphore mySemaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1, "SemaphoreTest");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Blocks forever if the first process was terminated
            // before it had the chance to call Release
            Console.WriteLine("Getting semaphore");
            mySemaphore.WaitOne();  
            Console.WriteLine("Acquired...");
        }
        catch (AbandonedMutexException)
        {
            // Never called!
            Console.WriteLine("Acquired due to AbandonedMutexException...");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(20 * 1000);
        mySemaphore.Release();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: Semaphores do not have owners. There is no such thing as semaphore abandonment. If you want automatic release when the thread exits, use a mutex.

Comment: @George: See my updated answer, which shows you how to be notified when the user closes the window.

Comment: You can never ignore a process abort when you are doing interop like this.  There are few cases where it is meaningful to keep running, a lot of implicit state has disappeared.  Break the deadlock with the Process.Exited event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you *can't* guarantee that a thread releases a semaphore when the thread exits. You can write try/finally blocks and critical finalizers, but those won't always work if the program terminates abnormally. And, unlike mutexes, other threads won't be notified if a thread exits while it still holds the semaphore.

The reason is that the [Windows semaphore object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), on which the .NET Semaphore object is based, doesn't keep track of which threads have acquired it, and therefore can't throw an exception similar to the `AbandonedMutexException`.

That said, you *can* be notified when the user closes the window. You need to set a control handler to listen to particular events. You call the Windows API function [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing it a callback function (delegate) that handles the events you're interested in. It's been a while since I did this, but in general.

Create a managed prototype for the `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` function, and the callback:

```
/// <summary>
/// Control signals received by the console control handler.
/// </summary>
public enum ConsoleControlEventType: int
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A CTRL+C signal was received, either from keyboard input or from a
    /// signal generated by the GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent function.
    /// </summary>
    CtrlC = 0,
    /// <summary>
    /// A CTRL+BREAK signal was received, either from keyboard input or from
    /// a signal generated by GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent.
    /// </summary>
    CtrlBreak = 1,
    /// <summary>
    /// A signal that the system sends to all processes attached to a console
    /// when the user closes the console (either by clicking Close on the console
    /// window's window menu, or by clicking the End Task button command from
    /// Task Manager).
    /// </summary>
    CtrlClose = 2,
    // 3 and 4 are reserved, per WinCon.h
    /// <summary>
    /// A signal that the system sends to all console processes when a user is logging off. 
    /// </summary>
    CtrlLogoff = 5,
    /// <summary>
    /// A signal that the system sends to all console processes when the system is shutting down. 
    /// </summary>
    CtrlShutdown = 6
}

/// <summary>
/// Control event handler delegate.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="CtrlType">Control event type.</param>
/// <returns>Return true to cancel the control event.  A return value of false
/// will terminate the application and send the event to the next control
/// handler.</returns>
public delegate bool ConsoleCtrlHandlerDelegate(ConsoleControlEventType CtrlType);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(
ConsoleCtrlHandlerDelegate HandlerRoutine,
bool Add);
```

Now, create your handler method:

```
private static bool ConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleControlEventType CtrlType)
{
    switch (CtrlType)
    {
        case CtrlClose:
            // handle it here
            break;
        case CtrlBreak:
            // handle it here
            break;
    }
    // returning false ends up calling the next handler
    // returning true will prevent further handlers from being called.
    return false;
}
```

And, finally, during initialization you want to set the control handler:

```
SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleControlHandler);
```

Your control handler will now be called when the user closes the window. That will allow you to release the semaphore or do other cleanup.

You might be interested in my [ConsoleDotNet package](http://mischel.com/pubs/consoledotnet/consoledotnet.zip). I wrote three articles about this stuff, the last two of which are still available at DevSource. I don't know what happened to the first one.

- [Console Input in .NET](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Console-Input-in-NET/)
- [Working with Console Screen Buffers in .NET](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Working-with-Console-Screen-Buffers-in-NET/)

Comment: 99.999% of the time Critical Finalizers are 'the' appropriate mechanism for cleaning up kernel objects during normal (and unexpected) terminations. In the other 0.001% you probably need to reboot, reformat or replace the problematic computer and not "code defensively" for "unstable environments". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.constrainedexecution.criticalfinalizerobject.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can write the mySemaphore.Release(); in class destructor

```
class Program
{
    ~Program()  // destructor
    {
        mySemaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

or add a finally pharse to your try\catch

```
try{}
catch{}
finally 
{
    mySemaphore.Release();
}
```

If you are using asp.net you can also use Application_End which located in Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_End(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    mySemaphore.Release();
}
```

Comment: Basically: Do not ignore the exit paths but clean up when you get stopped.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those helps. There is no instance of Program, and even if there is, the destructor is not called when you close the console window or press Ctrl+C. The finally block would only be executed if Thread.Sleep would throw an exception when you terminate the program, which it doesn't. I don't work with ASP.net, either. I have also tried Console.CancelKeyPress, which works for Ctrl+C but not for closing the window. AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit is not called either.

Comment: Finalizers (not dtors) are not guaranteed to execute.