# What is the correct usage for sqlite on locking or async

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, locking, async-await

We are using Xamarin to write C# code with SQLite for android and ios. However about how to use sqlite, I seem to have a conceptual misunderstanding:

[What are the best practices for SQLite on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493331/what-are-the-best-practices-for-sqlite-on-android)

According to the stackoverflow answer it says  - one helper and one db connection. Use lock around it to make sure only one thread is accessing sqlite db at any time.

My question is - if that is the case - what is the use for async?

I tried to use async with synchronized code - and the code gave me compile errors rightfully to avoid deadlocks.
[Why can't I use the 'await' operator within the body of a lock statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612602/why-cant-i-use-the-await-operator-within-the-body-of-a-lock-statement)

```
    public async Task InsertAsync<T> (T item){
        lock (mutex) {
            await asyncConnection.InsertAsync (item);
        }
    }

    public async Task InsertOrUpdateAsync<T> (T item){
        lock (mutex) {
            int count = await asyncConnection.UpdateAsync (item);
            if (0 == count) {
                await asyncConnection.InsertAsync (item);
            }
        }
    }
```

fails. However - if I am going to use locks to ensure I am using one connection one thread at a time as a best practice in sqlite - why is there an async sqlite library at all?

And why are some threads promoting async sqlite usage on the web.

What is the real best practice for sqlite in android and iphone? Just using sync version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a big difference between *synchronous vs asynchronous* and *single vs concurrent* and there are all 4 combinations of them.

In the *single* *asynchronous* case you access the DB using a single thread at most, but it doesn't need to be the same thread throughout the operation, and when you don't need a thread (when you are waiting for the `IO` operation to complete) you don't need any threads at all.

The most basic way to limit the `async` usage to a single operation at a time is by using a `SemaphoreSlim` with `initialCount = 1`. A nicer way would be to use an `AsyncLock` ([Building Async Coordination Primitives, Part 6: AsyncLock](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-6-asynclock/) by Stephen Toub):

```
private readonly AsyncLock _lock = new AsyncLock(); 

public async Task InsertAsync<T> (T item)
{
    using(await _lock.LockAsync())
    {
        await asyncConnection.InsertAsync (item);
    }
}

public async Task InsertOrUpdateAsync<T> (T item)
{
    using(await _lock.LockAsync())
    {
        if (0 == await asyncConnection.UpdateAsync (item))
        {
            await asyncConnection.InsertAsync (item);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: [My implementation of `AsyncLock`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21011273/885318)

Comment: The only difference i see is the `using` statement. Internally it uses an `AsyncSemaphore`, which frankly im not sure how it differes from a `SemaphoreSlim`. Are there any other benefits?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov In my implementation it uses `SemaphoreSlim`. The benefit is you use what you need, and what you need is an **async lock scope** so you encapsulate all the decisions into a class. That encourages reuse and reduces bugs like yours where you neglected to release the sempahore.

Comment: It's the difference between using `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` directly instead of using a `lock`. While you *could* do that, you *shouldn't*.

Comment: Right, so the benefit is encapsulation of the lock. I was looking to see if there are any functional differences between the two.

Comment: I am currently trying your solution. I believe you refer to [your code here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468137/async-network-operations-never-finish) for the disposable scope item (it gave a compilation error) - will let you know once I try

Comment: @user3141326 yes. It's just a generic idisopsable type.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that your Database doesn't accept multiple accesses (insertions, updates, etc..) doesn't mean that the single thread doing work against it has to do so using a blocking api.

If you don't have to do cross-process locking, you can use `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` instead of your `Mutex` inside your async method to await the lock asynchrnously:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 1);

public async Task InsertAsync<T>(T item)
{
   await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
   try
   {
      await asyncConnection.InsertAsync(item);
   }
   finally
   { 
      semaphoreSlim.Release();
   }
}

public async Task InsertOrUpdateAsync<T>(T item)
{
   await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
   try
   {      
      int count = await asyncConnection.UpdateAsync(item);
      if (0 == count) 
      {
         await asyncConnection.InsertAsync(item);
      }
   }
   finally
   {
      semaphoreSlim.Release();
   }
}
```

Comment: What if you need to do cross-process locking? On Android, I have Android Service which need to write to database, and I'd like the Android Service to run in a separate process.

Comment: @DonBox Mutexes are thread-affine, so you're not going to have much luck in that area. Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153155/named-mutex-with-await can give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you. Does that also apply to Xamarin?