# Global Mutex with Async Await

Tags: c#, async-await, mutex

I have a critical section of code that should be run by only one process at a time.  To ensure only one process on the machine is ever running this critical block I use a global Mutex.  The code in the critical section uses async/await.  Overall the code looks something like this:

```
var mutex = new Mutex(false, @"Global\MyMutexName");    
mutex.WaitOne(-1, false);   
SetupASystemWideResource() 
await DoSomeAsyncWorkOnThatResource();    
mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

The issue is that the code after the await can happen on a different thread.  So the mutex could get released on a different thread than it was acquired.  This causes an exception

```
System.ApplicationException: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
```

Normally this would make since you dont want a different thread releasing the mutex than acquiring it.  However in my case I am really only interested in preventing a 2nd instance of the application from setting up the system resource in a different way while the first instance is using it.  The resource itself is fine to be used from multiple threads within the one instance.

What is the correct way to ensure this and also do the work asynchronously?

Comment: Can you do that on UI thread (assuming WinFroms/WPF)?

Answer (score 4):

If i understand the problem, and this is a console app or there is no synchronisation context, just call `Wait`, there is no fear of a deadlock and it should work fine

```
var mutex = new Mutex(false, @"Global\MyMutexName");    
mutex.WaitOne(-1, false);

DoSomeAsyncWorkOnThatResource().Wait();
mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

---

Or if you really must (and more controversially) you could use

```
Task.Run(async () => await DoSomeAsyncWorkOnThatResource()).Wait();
```

---

The other thing you can do is use a custom Scheduler like `CurrentThreadTaskScheduler` (first time i have seen you use for it), as described in *Stephen Toubs* [Parallel Programming with .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/09/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/). Nuget [ParallelExtensionsExtras](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ParallelExtensionsExtras/)

> runs all tasks on the current thread when scheduling is requested

And use it with `Task.Factory.StartNew` or something that takes a scheduler

Comment: I found `DoSomeAsyncWorkOnThatResource().Wait();` to be a great way to get around the `await` problem.

Answer (score 3):

A Semaphore does not have the requirement that it be released by the same thread.  So the below works even when the async method continues on a different thread.  The big disadvantage here is if the application crashes or is killed during the work the semaphore will not be released so the next run of the app will hang. See [Abandoned named semaphore not released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262381/abandoned-named-semaphore-not-released)

```
var semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1, @"Global\MySemaphoreName");    
semaphore.WaitOne(-1, false);   
SetupASystemWideResource() 
await DoSomeAsyncWorkOnThatResource();    
semaphore.Release();
```